# SQL Server Reporting Service and Web Forms

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, webforms, data-access

Here is the background: I have a database with some tables, now need to decide how to access data, including SELECT by ProductName, generate statistics number and Graphs or Charts, and PDF download.

So I used to use old-fashioned Web Forms with ADO.NET, like `SqlDataSource`, adapter, datasets, etc to display data in a GridView.

But recently I learnt that SQL Server has SSRS (Reporting Services).

I am wondering what's difference between GridView and Reporting Services, I know you can integrate Reporting in Web Forms, but I want to know which way is better to display data, graph, charts, statistics in a web application??

Thanks so much for your advice.....

Comment: Well, reporting services are **specifically** designed to do reporting, including charting. I think it could save you **a lot of manual work** if you can use ready-made, ready-to-use components like SSRS ....

Comment: @marc_s has the best answer here.  There's nothing you can do in SSRS that you couldn't recreate via a web app of some sort, even leveraging SSRS controls as mentioned below.  What SSRS allows for though is rapid development and deployment.  A report that could take an hour to build might be a week long endeavor to make into a webpage.  The simpler toolset also allows for less experienced developers to easily create reports, without needing to know the annals of web development.  SSRS is a great tool to give to an in-house BI team, so you can free up dev resources for other matters.

Answer (score 0):

As far as my concern goes you won't be able to implement SSRS in a Web Form since SSRS is a whole application/service, unless you use a frame inside your Web Form to display the SSRS website then you won't be able to use it.

There are several approaches for this task:

1. You can use SSDT -> Sql Server Data Tools which is the shell version of Visual Studio, with the necessary tools for you to be able to design packages for SSIS, reports for SSRS and models for SSAS. It ships in with your SQL Server Installer (2012+), or it can be downloaded from the MS website, for the installers of SQL Server 2008 R2 or older the SSDT was called BIDS -> Business Intelligence Development Studio. The report created here would be used for the SSRS website.
2. Another easier way to create a report is using Report Builder, it is much more simpler and easy to learn as it is almost a drag and drop application. (Requires at least SQL Server 2008 R2)
3. If you want to make the report part of the Web Form application you can use the Report Viewer controller in Visual Studio, As far as I know it comes already in the .NET framework 2.0. I am not sure if for this option the Reporting Services must be installed or not.

Regards.

**UPDATE**

I kind of got lost in the topic while writing the reply, GridView is just a 2D visualization, it is as in an Excel Sheet, so the data will be just text.

I guess it all depends of what your client wants, if the data is about sales income, I am sure a line graph will be mush easier that just providing 9 digits numbers for each month.

If the data will be used by your client to make other operations, like adding all the sales income, then divide by 12 to have an average, etc. then a GridView might be the way to go.

Perhaps both ways are the easier way?

**Remember that in SSRS you can implement also a table view, so it will replace the GridView and you can additionally add graphs to it. It would be a 2 in one solution.**

Comment: Awesome, thanks for reply. The requirement is to display data base on user search, eg. Date, and generate some line graph or pie charts for statistics. Also generate PDF for download and print. So I am not sure either use Web forms with GridView, or use SSRS??? So how do you think? Thanks again.

Comment: This answer is misleading - you can *easily* make use of a ReportViewer control in ASP.NET applications to display SSRS reports - it's quite simple to plop one onto a page.

Comment: Kyzen, my point 3 states that the report viewer controller can be used in VS, but in point 1 I said that the web application which comes with SSRS can't be partially inserted into another web application unless is something like a frame.
The post does not go in a straight forward line, I jumped between topics, but this is not an excuse for you to don't read the whole post in which I clearly explained that the report viewer controller can be used ;)
Thanks for your opinion tho.

Comment: BBC - If you want to get nitpicky, Report View Controls can be set to local processing mode, which cuts out the need for an SSRS server entirely, which is why I said your answer is *misleading* - I did not say you were *wrong*...  though, you were wrong about one thing - Report Builder has been available since 2005 (and possibly even 2000  SP4/RS SP2?), not 2008 R2 ;)

Comment: I didn't know that you can process a report locally without SSRS. And regarding to Report Builder I have made a mistake, I was thinking in only about RB 3.0. Thanks for the feedback :)